# How to pass variable to sed "$(sed -n '/110600002019/ =' tmuser.cf | tail -n 1)" 's/110600002019 /120700002019/' tmuser.cf

Tags: unix, scripting

I want the variable to be passed as below.
a=110600002019 
b=120700002019

```
  sed "$(sed -n '/$a/ =' tmuser.cf | tail -n 1)" 's/$a /$b/' tmuser.cf
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "$(sed -n "/$a/ =" tmuser.cf | tail -n 1) s/$a /$b/" tmuser.cf
```

Worked for me. I made a small test file

```
cat tmuser.cf
a
110600002019
b
c
120700002019
```

Wasn't sure about the `120700002019` so I put it in the file.

The output from the script above is

```
a
120700002019
b
c
120700002019
```

Note that you can learn a lot for debugging a problem like this by wrapping your command with

```
set -vx ; ... your cmnds .... ; set +vx
```

Doing so yielded the first clue

```
sed "$(sed -n '/$a/ =' tmuser.cf | tail -n 1)" 's/$a /$b/' tmuser.cf
1 >sed -n '/$a/ =' tmuser.cf
1 >tail -n 1
1 >sed '' 's/$a /$b/' tmuser.cf
sed: s/$a /$b/: cannot open [No such file or directory]    
a
110600002019
b
c
120700002019
```

None of the variables are being replaced with their values. You need to use dbl-quotes so variables can be substituted.

And the error message

```
sed: s/$a /$b/: cannot open [No such file or directory]
```

tells us that `sed` thinks that `s/$a /$b/` is a filename, not a command. All commands have to appear as one unbroken string to the shell that is passing them to `sed`, so notice how I've changed

```
...| tail -n 1)" 's/$a /$b/'...
```

to

```
...|  tail -n 1)  s/$a /$b/"....
```

IHTH